# Defining operator with the inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $E\colon \Omega\times \mathbb{S}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{d}$, $\varepsilon\colon \Omega\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^{d}$, $\varepsilon$ is a linear and bounded operator and $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Let $V$ be a Hilbert space with the following inner product

$$(u,v)_{V}=\int_{\Omega}\varepsilon(u)\cdot \varepsilon(v) \,dx.$$
I want to express the following integral
$$\int_{\Omega}E\varepsilon (u)\cdot \varepsilon(v) \,dx$$
in the form of operator $A \colon V\rightarrow V$ which satifsies the equality

$$(Au,v)_{V}=\int_{\Omega}E\varepsilon (u)\cdot \varepsilon (v) \,dx.$$

**How can I do that and more importantly, does such an operator exist at all?**

My considerations are as follows:

Let us introduce $f\colon V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}E\varepsilon (u)\cdot \varepsilon (v) \,dx.\qquad (1)$$

Since we don't know much about $E$ I can not state that $f$ is bilinear, but at least it is continuous and linear with respect to the second variable. Hence, fix $u\in V$. By the Riesz representation theorem there exists unique $a_{u}\in V$ such that for all $v\in V$ we have:

$$f(u,v)=(a_{u},v)_{V}.\qquad (2)$$
Combining (1) and (2) we obatain that $E\varepsilon(u)=\varepsilon(a_{u})$ almost everywhere. That's as much as I can squeeze out of the Riesz theorem for the time being. **Can $A$ be defined as follows
$$Au=a_u\, ?$$**